# Correct way to use cin.fail()

Tags: c++, cin

What is the correct way to use `cin.fail();`?

I am making a program where you need to input something.  It is not very clear if you need to input a number or character.  When a user inputs a character instead of a number the console goes crazy.  How can I use `cin.fail()` to fix this?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Shumail92 I currently don't have it.

Comment: For a situation like this, you'd usually read a character, then check if it's a digit (and if so, convert to a number).

Comment: You could use a good C++ book. but have a look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail

Comment: @JerryCoffin Okay, I'll do that, but I would still like to learn to use `cin.fail()`.

Comment: @hetepeperfan I do have a good book.  It just doesn't have anything about this.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'd do the opposite.  Getting things like skipping white space and reinserting the character in the stream right isn't obvious to a beginner.

Comment: btw, +1 for your question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cin.fail()` returns true if the last cin command failed, and false otherwise.

An example:

```
int main() {
  int i, j = 0;

  while (1) {
    i++;
    cin >> j;
    if (cin.fail()) return 0;
    cout << "Integer " << i << ": " << j << endl;  
  }
}
```

Now suppose you have a text file -  input.txt and it's contents are:

```
  30 40 50 60 70 -100 Fred 99 88 77 66
```

When you will run above short program on that, it will result like:

```
  Integer 1: 30
  Integer 2: 40
  Integer 3: 50
  Integer 4: 60
  Integer 5: 70
  Integer 6: -100
```

it will not continue after 6th value as it quits after reading the seventh **word**, because that is not an integer: `cin.fail()` returns `true`.

Comment: @hetepeperfan numerically speaking 0 is the only false value.

Comment: Yeah but it will work in this situation - i edited answer and added `int main()` as well.

Comment: Something's wrong here (in addition to the poor formatting).
First, of course, `std::istream::fail()` never returns
"non-zero" or "zero": it returns `true` or `false`.  Second, on
the given text file it outputs everything, **-100** is an
integer, and `std::cin.fail()` will return `false` after reading
it.

Comment: This fails when entering `1.2` or `1,2`

Comment: @JamesKanze "non-zero" and "zero" ARE true and false respectively in C++.

Comment: @Peon That's because those aren't integers.

Answer (score 26):

`std::cin.fail()` is used to test whether the preceding input
succeeded.  It is, however, more idiomatic to just use the
stream as if it were a boolean:

```
if ( std::cin ) {
    //  last input succeeded, i.e. !std::cin.fail()
}

if ( !std::cin ) {
    //  last input failed, i.e. std::cin.fail()
}
```

In contexts where the syntax of the input permit either a number
of a character, the usual solution is to read it by lines (or in
some other string form), and parse it; when you detect that
there is a number, you can use an `std::istringstream` to 
convert it, or any number of other alternatives (`strtol`, or
`std::stoi` if you have C++11).

It is, however, possible to extract the data directly from the
stream:

```
bool isNumeric;
std::string stringValue;
double numericValue;
if ( std::cin >> numericValue ) {
    isNumeric = true;
} else {
    isNumeric = false;
    std::cin.clear();
    if ( !(std::cin >> stringValue) ) {
        //  Shouldn't get here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I never knew that was possible.  Thank you!