# Infinite while loop happens when asking user for 2 numbers

Tags: c++, do-while

I'm trying to implement a simple game where user is asked for 2 valid integer coordinates between 0 and 10. (int row, int column)

An exemple of what I would realize is:

Insert coordinates: 4C
*Error, number of row and column must be integer

Insert coordinates: 44 2
*Error, number of row or column are too high

Insert coordinates: 4 3
The coordinates you entered are (4,3)

I realized all of these with a do-while cycle.

```
int r,c;
do{
cout<<"Insert coordinates: ";
cin>>r>>c;
    if (cin.fail())
{
    cout << "ERROR: Number of row and column must be integer." << endl << endl;

}
    if ((r<0 || r>10) || (c<0 || c>10)
{
    cout << "*Error, number of row or column are too high [0-10]" << endl << endl;

}
 cout<<endl;
}
while (((r<0 || r>10)||(c<0 || c>10)) || cin.fail());
```

This code doesn't work properly. If I enter 2 numbers between 0 and 10, it works. If I enter a number bigger then 10, it also works. But if I entered a character the program goes into an infinite loop, and does not work properly.

How to implement this to handle errors with character input? Is there a way to recognize, and remain inside the while cycle, if user inputs a character?

Comment: What do you want it to do if the user enters a wrong value?

Comment: Not sure if it's affecting it but you're missing an end parenthesis on the line `if ((r<0 || r>10) || (c<0 || c>10)`

Comment: `cin.fail()` is not triggered if a char is entered

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928865/correct-way-to-use-cin-fail

Comment: @Samoth If extraction fails because a letter is entered instead of a number, `failbit` is set. You might want to check e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a letter instead of a number, then that letter is not extracted from the input buffer, so your code will continue to fail forever.

If the input fails (why not use e.g. `if (!(cin >> r >> c))`?) then you can skip the line by doing calling the [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) function:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You also want to clear the `failbit`  as it's not cleared automatically, this is done with the [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function.

---

You can also bypass this problem by getting the whole line, and using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for the parsing:

```
do
{
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, line))
        ... // Could not read from input

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int r, c;
    if (!(iss >> r >> c))
        ... // Failed to parse as numbers

    ...

} while (...);
```

Comment: Pulling it out of an input stream and putting it into another input stream to read in is a bit overkill.

Comment: @ZacHowland Not always, it can simplify things, especially since you no longer have the problem that the `std::cin` stream will get the `failbit` set on erroneous input, or that some characters will linger in the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(((r<0 || r>10)||(c<0 || c>10)) || cin.fail());
```

change to

```
 (((r>0) && (r<10))||((c>0) && (c<10)))     //It will work, no need to check cin.fail();
```

If cin fails then it might produce errors in buffer so better to quit the program..

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check if characters were entered, for example:

```
if (x >= 0x41 && x <= 0x7A)
cout<<"error, you entered a letter";
```

Answer (score 0):

The program goes into an infinite loop because you never clear the fail state.  You can simplify your [entire loop](http://ideone.com/NHLD0H):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int r = -1;
    int c = -1;
    bool valid = false;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Insert coordinates: ";
        if (cin >> r >> c)
        {
            if (r >= 0 && r <= 10 && c >= 0 && c <= 10)
            {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }

        if (!valid)
        {
            cout << "ERROR:  Number of row and column must be an integer between 0 and 10." << endl;
        }
    } while (!valid);

    cout << "You entered (" << r << ", " << c << ")" << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also with your code, the do-while goes into an infinite loop if I entered for example " a 4". :/

Comment: It does not.  It will loop around again asking you for the input again (because your first input failed), clear the state, and let you retry *until* you enter valid input.

Comment: try to compile it and run! If i entered a number bigger than 10 it end cycle, while i would ask user another input. If i entered a char goes in loop.

Comment: What you just said makes no sense.  This only breaks out of the loop when you enter valid numbers between 0 and 10, inclusive.

Comment: I think I did forget to transpose the `cin.ignore` call though.  Fixed in the compiled example.