# How is (cin) evaluated?

Tags: c++

In Bjarne Stroustrup's *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ (Sixth Printing, November 2012)*, `if (cin)` and `if (!cin)` are introduced on p.148 and used in earnest on p.178. `while (cin)` is introduced on p.183 and used in earnest on p.201.

However, I feel I don't fully understand how these constructs work, so I'm exploring them.

If I compile and run this:

```
int main()
{
        int i = 0 ;
        while (cin) {
                cout << "> ";
                cin >> i ;
                cout << i << '\n';
        }
}
```

I get something like:

```
$ ./spike_001
> 42
42
> foo
0
$
```

- Why is it that entering "foo" apparently causes `i` to be set to `0`?
- Why is it that entering "foo" causes `cin` to be set to `false`?

Alternatively, if I run and compile this:

```
int main()
{
        int i = 0 ;
        while (true) {
                cout << "> ";
                cin >> i ;
                cout << i << '\n';
        }
}
```

I get something like:

```
$ ./spike_001
> 42
42
> foo
> 0
> 0
...
```

The last part of user input here is `foo`. After that is entered, the line `> 0` is printed to stdout repeatedly by the program, until it is stopped with Ctrl+C.

- Again, why is it that entering "foo" apparently causes `i` to be set to `0`?
- Why is it that the user is not prompted for a new value for `i` on the next iteration of the while loop after `foo` was entered?

This is using `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`.

I'm sorry for such a long question, but I think it all boils down to, "How is cin evaluated?"

Comment: you need to check the error flags. The issue is you are trying to feed a string `"foo"` into an integer `i`. `cin` normally performs the type conversions necessary when using the `>>` operator, but there's no way to convert `"foo"` to an int.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928865/correct-way-to-use-cin-fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `std::cin` (or more precisely [`std::basic_ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios)) has an [`operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to implicitly convert the `std::cin` object to a `bool` when requested (for example in your `if` evaluation).

The semantic is as follows:

> Checks whether the stream has no errors. Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

---

> Why is it that entering "foo" apparently causes i to be set to 0?
>
> Again, why is it that entering "foo" apparently causes i to be set to 0?

Because `operator>>` on an `int` expects an integer in the string.

From [`cppreference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.

---

> Why is it that entering "foo" causes cin to be set to false?

Because the fail bit is set, therefore leading `fail()` to return `true`.

---

> Why is it that the user is not prompted for a new value for i on the next iteration of the while loop after foo was entered?

That is because `std::cin` has the fail bit set, therefore it fails to get the input and just prints the old value of `i` which is `0`.

Comment: Thanks :) You say, "If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified..." But the value *isn't* left unmodified: it is instead changed from (e.g.) `42` to `0`.

Comment: Ah, from [the cppreference page you linked](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt), I see that "since C++11", "If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set." So, I guess the compiler is defaulting to C++11 :)

Comment: @sampablokuper, when in doubt on the standard library, just turn to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/). It's a good source. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `>>` operator on a stream, it *attempts* to extract a value of that type from the string. In other words, when you do `cin >> i` where `i` is an `int`, the stream attempts to pull an `int` from the stream. If this succeeds, `i` is set to the extracted value, and all is well. If it fails, the stream's `badbit` is set. This is important because treating a stream as a bool is equivalent to checking if it's `badbit` is set (`if (cin)` is like `if (cin.good())`).

So anyway... what's happening is that foo is setting the badbit since the extraction fails. Really, you should be checking if the extraction succeeds directly:

```
if (cin >> i) { /* success */ }
```

---

On a code quality note, I suspect you're using `using namespace std;`. Please be aware that this [can be harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/567864).

Comment: Thanks. `if (cin >> i)` already made sense to me intuitively, but although Stroustrup uses it on some occasions, it's not what he uses in his examples on the pages I've mentioned. Since I want to understand all the examples, that means I also need to understand `if (cin)` and `while (cin)`.

Comment: @sampablokuper If it helps make sense, `operator>>` on streams actually returns itself. So the return of `cin >> i` is `cin`. This is what allows the implicit bool conversion and what allows you to do more complex chaining like `cin >> i >> s >> f >> ...`.