# How internally string/char is stored in int and float

Tags: c++

I have **MISTAKENLY** found the scenario while executing the following block of code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int input1;
    float input2;

    cout << "Enter a real number :";
    cin >> input1;
    cout << "The int number is " << input1 << endl;

    cout << "Enter another number :";
    cin >> input2;
    cout << "The float number is " << input2 << endl;
}
```

The output for the above is

```
Enter a real number :a
The int number is -858993460
Enter another number :a
The float number is -1.07374e+08
```

Can anyone kindly explain how internally the above scenario is getting handled resulting in the above scenario ?

**Note** -

- Running the above in VS2015.

As i am newly experimenting with C++, please point me to any reference if i have missed in the process.

Comment: What is `input`? It's not declared in your example.

Comment: Have you checked the fail bit - It might have not been a number

Comment: @mpiatek input in both cases is 'a' and the output is same for int and float for all the cases without any changes

Comment: @EdHeal I do not want to do fail check(i know i should have done). But i want to know how internally those same values are coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int input1;
float input2;
```

At this point, both `input1` and `input2` have undefined values since you didn't initialize them.

`std::cin` was expecting an integer to be entered but you entered `'a'`, which made `std::cin` to `fail`. That failure persists such that no extraction operation can be performed with `std::cin` until the `failbit` is cleared.

After your failed input operations, `input1` and `input2` are still "undefined". Printing them lead to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Yes you are right, indeed the correct behaviour, i initialized them with 0 and now the output seems to be correct even if i give a wrong input. 
Thanks for the explanation. I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: Use `if(!cin)cout<<"failed";` after `cin>>input` to verify that `cin` actually failed.

Comment: @GauravSehgal thanks for the input... it worked as you said.

Comment: @sasuke, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928865/correct-way-to-use-cin-fail), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input), and the [states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) that `std::cin` can assume

Comment: or even `if (cin >> input1)`

Comment: @WhiZTiM  thanks for your responses. Got to know something new even by making such silly mistake.

Comment: @mpiatek , yes your suggestion is pretty quick one. Thanks .

Comment: Note that C++11 changed this to store 0 on failure, at least for `int`. I assume it's the same for floating-point overloads.

Answer (score 2):

The extraction operator does not change the variables when the stream cannot be interpreted as a valid value of the appropriate type. Therefore you see uninitialized values for `input1` and `input2`. You can check the `failbit` on `cin` to see whether the extraction operator was successful.

For example:

```
    int input1;
    cout << "Enter a real number :";
    cin >> input1;
    if(cin.good())
    {
        cout << "The int number is " << input1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
       cout << "The input was not a number." << endl;

       // skip to the end of the input
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    }
```

Comment: Yes , it can also be handled as you suggested here. Thanks for the response.