# What's the difference between cin.fail() and !cin in C++?

Tags: c++, input, error-handling, stream, cin

I'm studying the different input errors in **C++**. I understand that **!cin** returns true when there's any problem establishing an input stream. But I can't clearly appreciate the difference with **cin.fail()**. Can anyone clarify it for me please?

Comment: What's unclear from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to use cin.fail()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928865/correct-way-to-use-cin-fail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are same. `fail` is a typical function where is '!' is an overloaded operator. You may want to check reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/ before posting.
[image]

Comment: OK, my bad, sorry.