# Strange behavior of std::cin while entering floating point numbers for integer defined variable

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, visual-studio-2019, cin

Recently one of my beginner C++ developers-friends showed me a non-industrial piece of code where he wanted to learn entities of **loops**, **`std::cin`**, and **`std::cout`** concepts. Let me introduce a problem briefly.
He has to enter via `std::cin` the number of numbers that he needs to insert from the keyboard in order to count the average of that numbers. Here is the code(please do not be critical to the code).

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int amount = 0;
    
    std::cout << "Please insert amount of numbers you want to enter"<<'\n';
    
    std::cin >> amount;
    
    std::cout << "You have to enter "<< amount <<" numbers"<<'\n';
    
    if (amount < 1){
        std::cout << "You entered invalid number" << '\n';
        
        std::cout << "Average is "<< 0.0 <<'\n';
    }
    else{
            float current = 0.0;
            
            float total_sum = 0.0;
            
            for ( int i = 1; i <= amount; ++i){
                
                std::cout << "Insertion " << i <<": Please enter any number" << '\n';
                std::cin >> current;   
                total_sum += current;
            }
            std::cout << "Average is " << total_sum/amount << '\n';
        }
    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine when we insert integer values via `std::cin` for the `amount` variable, but whenever we enter any floating-point number for `amount` the code starts doing strange things. For example here is the behavior when I inserted `3.14`

```
Please insert amount of numbers you want to enter
3.14
You have to enter 3 numbers
Insertion 1: Please enter any number
Insertion 2: Please enter any number
```

I even checked for extra convenience what value will be assigned to `amount` in such cases, and the result is predictable that it will narrow the value and assign it to the variable. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an explanation to this issue and hope I can do it with your assistance.

Comment: Why are you attempting to enter a `float`?  What did you expect to happen when you entered something that wasn't an `int`?

Comment: Entering float is not a good idea, but even if I do it I think it shouldn't behave like this, it narrows the value, so no problem should be, especially if that fragment of code where misbehaving occurs

Comment: [cin.fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928865/correct-way-to-use-cin-fail).  The input expects a digit, not a `.` character.  So now what is the stream going to do when it sees that character?  Jump over it and start with the `1`? (the stream is still in a fail state).

Comment: Once you have read `3` as an integer, the remaining input stream is `.14`. Then you try to read that as an integer.

Comment: **You have to enter 3 numbers** is the result  `std::cout << "You have to enter "<< amount <<" numbers"<<'\n';` statement, so it means `amount` became 3, and the program should go on in a normal way, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you guys, I understand whats the problem.